dplyr::filter(): check if each value in vector is within *at least one* of a set of ranges
I'm trying to filter a data frame using filter() in tidyverse/dplyr. Consider the following two data frames/tibbles:
library(tidyverse)

df.tofilter<-tibble(f=c(5,9),
                    name=c("Dog","Cat"))

df.tocheck<-tibble(l=c(0,2,4),
                   u=c(1,3,7)
                   )


My goal: return only the first row of df.tofilter, because f = 5 is between at least one of the number pairs [l,u] in the data frame df.tocheck (in this case, between [4,7]).
It's important here that the data frame I'm trying to filter has a different number of rows than the data frame listing the ranges to check against.
I've tried solutions like the following:
df.tofilter %>% filter(f >= df.tocheck$l & f <= df.tocheck$u) 
df.tofilter %>% filter(data.table::between(f, df.tocheck$l, df.tocheck$u))

And lots of variants, but they all fail with messages like:
! Incompatible vector lengths: length(x)==2 length(lower)==3 length(upper)==3. Each should be either length 1 or the length of the longest.


From looking at the help file for ?data.table::between - do you want df.tofilter[f %inrange% df.tocheck] ?

semi_join(df.tofilter, df.tocheck, join_by(between(f, l, u)))

There are several ways to do this. Here is one using another package called {ivs}:
df.tofilter = tibble::tibble(f=c(5,9), name=c("Dog","Cat"))
df.tocheck = tibble::tibble(l=c(0,2,4), u=c(1,3,7))

library(ivs)
library(dplyr)

df.tofilter |>
  filter(iv_between(f, with(df.tocheck, iv(l, u))))

# A tibble: 1 × 2
      f name 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     5 Dog  


The solutions proposed in the comments work, with minor edits in the case of %inrange%:
library(tidyverse)

df.tofilter<-tibble(f=c(5,9),
                    name=c("Dog","Cat"))

df.tocheck<-tibble(l=c(0,2,4),
                   u=c(1,3,7)
                   )

df.tofilter[df.tofilter$f %inrange% df.tocheck,]
semi_join(df.tofilter, df.tocheck, join_by(between(f, l, u)))

It appears that using %inrange% is faster when the dataset being filtered is small, but that semi_join() is marginally faster when the dataset being filtered is large.
library(microbenchmark)

df.tofilter<-tibble(f=rnorm(100)) # Smallish dataframe

microbenchmark(
  df.tofilter[df.tofilter$f %inrange% df.tocheck,],
  semi_join(df.tofilter, df.tocheck, join_by(between(f, l, u)))
)

Unit: microseconds
                                                          expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval cld
             df.tofilter[df.tofilter$f %inrange% df.tocheck, ] 412.7 451.75 535.828 502.10 537.65 1463.3   100  a 
 semi_join(df.tofilter, df.tocheck, join_by(between(f, l, u))) 771.1 825.85 921.927 859.05 933.65 1795.8   100   b

df.tofilter<-tibble(f=rnorm(100000)) # Larger dataframe

Unit: milliseconds
                                                          expr     min      lq     mean  median       uq     max neval cld
             df.tofilter[df.tofilter$f %inrange% df.tocheck, ] 15.5646 19.2805 22.77193 21.2589 25.42435 40.8984   100   a
 semi_join(df.tofilter, df.tocheck, join_by(between(f, l, u))) 14.9723 16.7478 21.06088 18.2492 22.53640 50.3692   100   a

